# How to reset dropdown on primefaces commandButton without java script?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to reset `<p:selectOneMenu>` in primeface. I used `type="reset"` this can reset the text fields only not a `selectonemenu`. My code

```
    <p:panel id="Applyleave_panel" >
      <p:selectOneMenu id="leavetype" value="#{requestbean.leavetype}" required="true" style="width:50%;">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select type" itemValue="" /> 
        <f:selectItems value="#{requestbean.leave_type}" />
      </p:selectOneMenu>
    </panel>
  <p:commandButton value="Reset" type="reset"/>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use **p:resetInput** given that your component is inside a form.

```
<p:commandButton value="Reset" update=":form" immediate="true">
                    <p:resetInput target=":form" />
                </p:commandButton>
```

EDIT: You can also target the **p:panel** component as well.

```
<p:commandButton value="Reset" update=":Applyleave_panel" immediate="true">
                        <p:resetInput target=":Applyleave_panel" />
                    </p:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the below

```
                <p:commandButton id="resetSearchCir" type="reset"
                            value="#{button.reset}" immediate="true">
                            <f:ajax event="click"
                                listener="#{searchBean.resetActionListener}" render="@form" />          
                        </p:commandButton>



                 public void resetActionListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
                    LOG.info("Reset button clicked...");
                    setResetClicked(true);
                    // re-initialise your form field objects which you want to reset
                    logWarn("All values have been reset. Please enter the new values to search again.");
                    }
```